# Why was is this question marked as off topic?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330683/how-to-get-return-information-as-a-post-with-google-open-id) was put on hold for being off topic, but all it is asking is how to do something. There are a lot of questions, especially by beginners, that ask simpler questions than that and are not put on hold.

The specific reason was:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

My questions are:

- What specific reason was question put on hold for?
- What could the author have added to make his question better?
- And shouldn’t it take more than one person to put a question on hold?

Comment: I appreciate someone taking an interest in my question

Comment: Usually it takes five people to put a question on hold. However, a moderator got to this one.

Comment: It only takes one to use a sock account.

Comment: [That](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2702232/aye?tab=reputation) surely smells like a sock puppet indeed, @Uphill. Did you flag already?

Comment: @Aye We're happy if you want to answer your own questions to gain reputation and you're free to edit other people's posts (with legitimate edits, obviously) to gain reputation. But we're not happy if you try to game the site with multiple accounts giving each other reputation. If both of those aren't your accounts, you just found yourself in a very, very suspicious situation.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking haha sock puppeting, you'll be in for a lot of trouble now

Comment: lol look at all these funny upvotes http://stackoverflow.com/users/2178017/taapsogeking?tab=reputation

Comment: @arjan That account link seems to be broken... ;)

Comment: @TAAPSogeking Nice, getting yourself suspended. Please do not make multiple accounts, it never ends well.

Comment: Be sure to read TAAPSogeking's profile bio, so you understand who you're dealing with here. SO will surely be a smoking ruin after he unleashes his abundant wrath.

Comment: @Michael, fantastic sock-pattern, lol indeed. Also, question is posted here, less than to minutes to switch accounts, posts first sock-comment.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I got the message. Sorry for any inconvenience I caused

Answer (score 4):

"all it is asking is how to do something" - it's not enough.

You are right that not all those type of question are been enforce consistently as
you can see in the following posts:

[Why aren't the rules for minimum research effort being enforced consistently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188049/why-arent-the-rules-for-minimum-research-effort-being-enforced-consistently).
[Why are some questions with no code or effort shown gets down voted while others up voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197562/why-are-some-questions-with-no-code-or-effort-shown-gets-down-voted-while-others)

**What specific reason was question put on hold for?** 
"all I need now is just how to get the information to always return as a post" - It's not so clear what the user is asking.

**What could the author have added to make his question better?**
The user didn't show a great deal of trying to face a specific problem.

**And shouldn’t it take more than one person to put a question on hold?**
It does, it takes 5 or a one that's really knows what he is doing.